# Do modern browsers encrypt or otherwise protect IndexedDB storage?

Tags: security, indexeddb, access-control

My team is considering using IndexedDB to cache data across user sessions. This data can be large enough that it would be a real performance boost to be able to keep it around in the browser for later use instead of having to download it every time the user needs it.

I am concerned about security problems with IndexedDB. The data in question isn't super sensitive, but there is a reason we require a user/pass to get to it. I worry that this data might be accessible if a user's laptop were stolen. Are these files sitting around unencrypted on the file system?

Comment: better thing to do is just encrypt the entire laptop drive to begin with. if you're worried about data in your db leaking, you'd probably also be worried about other stuff ELSEWHERE in the laptop leaking as well. Especially if the db's crypted - you'd have to store the decrypt credentials SOMEWHERE, and if that's in clear-text elsewhere on the drive, you've accomplished nothing.

Comment: even if he encrypted his file system, the plain text db would still be visible in his browsers storage, so this wouldn't accomplish all that much. @Kyaw Tun 's answer is the best approach

Answer (score 12):

You can encrypt before storing into indexeddb. That is how I do in my open source library, http://dev.yathit.com/ydn-db/doc/usage/encryption.html

One thing to note, encrypted database cannot be query. You can only retrieve with known primary key.

You still need to pass encryption key from the server after user login.

Answer (score 4):

Unless your users are using full disk encryption on their laptops, those files are sitting there unencrypted. You could consider encrypting the data you store using some javascript crypto with a key derived from the user's password.

Comment: If the user changes the password data is not accessible anymore

Comment: @Seb You should have a separate database key that is encrypted using a key derived from the user password. That way if the user password changes, just re-encrypt the database key. The database itself does not need to be re-encrypted.

Comment: What if I use OAuth? And I don't think having the user's password in a variable is a good idea